# How can I parse a NUMERIC(20) using sequelize before it converts the value to int

Tags: sql-server, node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli, tedious

I'm using mssql and my table have a NUMERIC(20) field. I'm trying to convert it to string on the get function but the `this.getDataValue('code')` is returning a truncated int (`8985353050864662000`)

```
code: {
  type: DataTypes.NUMBER(20),
  get() {
    return this.getDataValue('code').toString();
  }
}
```

The original number is a java UUID (`8985353050864661894`)

Comment: That is a mighty large number. Are you sure that you need to use a number here? Depending on what that number represents it may be that a varchar is actually more appropriate.

Comment: I totally agree. But this table was created for another application.